# Simple ChartJS Ionic Example - Gone Wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, ionic-framework, angular-chartist.js

I am trying to run a simple example of ionic with chartjs. Here is my Controller, I have added chart.js to my app.js, and the second is my graph.html page. I just get a blank white screen...

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic','ngCordova','chart.js']);
app.controller('graphCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ["Book1", "Book2", "Book3"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});


<ion-view view-title="Outline">
<ion-content>
    <canvas id="radar" class="chart chart-radar"
            chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
    </canvas>
    </ion-content> 

</ion-view>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the documentation for this?

https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js

Ionic is built upon angular, so angular-js plugins normally do work well with ionic. U might been missing a few dependencies or wrong syntax.

Comment: I think you might be correct, I need to use angular-chart and not charjs, ill give that a try

Comment: Cheers! Glad that I helped ya.